# what is max_iter and tol in Lasso Regularizer sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lasso-regression

According to the documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html, what does the max_iter and tol mean? Also how do I decide the value for max_iter and tol in order to have more control on the optimization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lasso regression has a unique optimum, but the solver is a sort of gradient descent algorithm, so you'll never actually reach the minimum.  `tol` controls how close you want to be: the smaller `tol`, the more accurate your final solution will be, but the longer it will take.  `max_iter` controls how many steps you'll take in the gradient descent before giving up.  The algorithm will stop when either updates are within `tol` or you've run for `max_iter` many steps; if the latter, you'll get a warning saying that the model hasn't converged (to within `tol`).

So, set `tol` to your liking, and set `max_iter` according to your computational resources.  Usually, go with the defaults and increase `max_iter` (and/or change solver, or scale your data if you haven't yet) if you get convergence warnings.